# send: invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, send, packet, sendto

I have a problem with this line of code. I must take a packet to a port and resend to interface(ex:eth0). My program successfully take packet from the port but when I resend (with `send()`) to interface I have an error:
**send:Invalid argument**

The line of code is:

```
    sock1=socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    sock2=socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    fd=fopen("port.txt","r+");
    if(fd) {
    while(!feof(fd)){
    fscanf(fd,"%d",&port);
    fscanf(fd, "%s",interface);
    }
}

memset(&source_addr,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
source_addr.sin6_family=AF_INET6;
source_addr.sin6_port=htons(port);
source_addr.sin6_addr=in6addr_any;



if(bind(sock1,(struct sockaddr*)&source_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6))==-1){perror("bind");}
//if(connect(sock1,(struct sockaddr*)&source_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6))==-1){perror("connect");}


//Device dove inviare
memset(&freq,0,sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(freq.ifr_name,interface,IFNAMSIZ);

if(ioctl(sock2,SIOCGIFINDEX,&freq)==-1){perror("ioctl");}
 memset(&destination_addr,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
 destination_addr.sin6_family=AF_INET6:
 destination_addr.sin6_scope_id=htonl(2)      
 inet_pton(AF_INET6,"2001::620:40b:555:110",(void*)&destination_addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
 if(bind(sock2,(struct sockaddr*)&destination_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)==-1)
 {perror("bind");}


if((buff=malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH))==NULL){ perror("malloc");}

packet_length=recv(sock1,buff,BUFFER_LENGTH,0);

if(packet_length<0){perror("recv");}

printf("La lunghezza è %d\n",packet_length);

packet=(unsigned char*)buff;

Sniffer(packet,packet_length,' ');


packet_length2=send(sock2,buff,BUFFER_LENGTH,0);
```

**buff** is packet that I take from port! Where is the error?

Comment: I think you might need to provide a bit more info and code here

Comment: @mathematician1975 i've edit!

Comment: Are u sure if sock2 is valid ?

Comment: @whoami i don'see an error when i create the socket, and bind...why is the error?

Comment: Sometimes we may get this error, if the destination_address is not built properly.

Comment: @Whoami but the destination address have all information that needed....i don't understand where is the error in my program!

Comment: Dont you need to listen and accept, or at least connect somewhere in there?

Comment: @mathematician1975 this isn't a communication client-server. I need to receive from port and redirect the packet to interface. I don't think thta listen and accept resolve my problem...

Comment: You call send() but you do not tell the socket where to send the data. You have to either: use sendto() or call connect() on sock2 to specify where to send the data. You call bind() with an argument named "destination_addr" , which does sound a bit strange, since bind() will be used as the source address on the socket when you send data..

Answer (score 3):

You did not call `connect()` on your UDP socket, so it doesn't have a default destination (to be used by `send()`). either call `connect()` to set the default destination, or use `sendto` with the explicit destination.

You should also not be sending more than you actually received (ie. `packet_length`)